# Separating console message from the code

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make command line apps. The `puts` line makes the code looks messy. For example, I have `help` command that has several `puts`

```
def help()
    puts "Welcome to my app"
    puts "..."
    puts "..."
    puts "..."
    puts "..."
end
```

If I combine the `puts` into one, the output will include the trailing space

```
def help()
    puts "Welcome to my app
    ...
    ..."
end

# The output in the console will be like:
# Welcome to my app
#        ...
#        ...
```

What's the best way to separate the message from the code? I can only think of using variable to store the message, but I believe there is a better, tidier way like markdown or using txt.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is `HERE` for actually?

Comment: To make your a code a little less "messy", you could simply define constants that reference multiple lines of text.  One way is to bracket the text with something like 'MGS_1 = %{' and '}'.  Another is to use a "here document".  You could do that by bracketing the text with something like 'MSG_1 = <<INSTRUCTIONS_1' and 'INSTRUCTIONS_1'.  You'd then just have 'puts MSG_1' in your code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, your comment and vgoff answer combined is what I exactly wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are asking, I think you are looking for the [OptParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) library in STDLIB.

It allows you to build command line options for doing things like usage and command line reporting for the user.

However, you can do this in your `help` method:

```
def help
  <<-EOS.lines.each {|line| line.strip!}
  Welcome to my app
  ...
  ...
  EOS
end
puts help
puts "Thank you for using my app!"
```

This will display like this.

```
Welcome to my app           
...                         
...                         
Thank you for using my app!
```

Update: I changed the EOF delimiter to EOS for End of String.

Answer (score 2):

```
def help
    puts \
    "Welcome to my app"\
    "..."\
    "..."\
    "..."\
    "..."\
    "..."
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still looks messy due to excessive `\` and `"`. vgoff's answer is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example, You can do within the help function

```
puts "Welcome to my app", "...\n"*3
```

If you have a lots of such static messages, you can try using a hash somewhere at the beginning

```
messages = {"welcome" => "Welcome to my app\n" + "...\n"*3, 
           "thanks" => "Thank you for the action"}
```

Then you can access them as

```
puts messages["welcome"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still looks messy due to `\n` and multiple `"`